# How can I create a back button that takes you back to the page you came from?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a button that knows what page you came from and enters that value into the anchor tag. Does anyone know a solution using either jQuery or PHP or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you could keep track of the last page the user was on by using

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

and storing it in the session.

```
$_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and run it after your html for the current page is rendered, then in a link you could have something like this

`<a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['last_page']; ?>">Back</a>`

Answer (score 10):

problem with

```
<a href="javascript:go(-1)">back</a>
```

?

Answer (score 3):

```
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.back()">
</FORM>
```

Also you can go back more pages, like this:

```
<FORM> <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1)"> </FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also - if u just want an

```
 <a href="javascript:go(-1)" class="dbutton" onClick="history.back()">Back</a>
```